# How to use QtQuick 2.2 components when my complete project is in QtQuick 1.1?

Tags: qml, qt-quick, qtquick2, qt5.2

My project was made using `QtQuick 1.1` and when I try to change it using `import QtQuick 2.2`, it shows error  `module "QtQuick" version 2.2 is not installed import QtQuick 2.2`.

I want to use `QtQuick 2.1` and `QtQuick 2.2` components. How can I do so?

I have :

```
Qt Creator 3.0.0
Based on Qt 5.2.0 (GCC 4.6.1, 32 bit)
Built on Dec 10 2013 at 11:47:52
From revision 27d10d8dcd
```

Comment: You can't, unless you port your application to `QtQuick 2.2`.

Comment: @user1095108 Sorry, but I have no idea about porting and all. Can you please help me a little with what to do with my current application?

Comment: Well, you really seem to not know a lot. This means your task will be easier. Try switching the import, as you wrote and the view your app with `qmlscene`, instead of with `qmlviewer`

Comment: are you compiling the code in QtCreator or using qmlscene or qmlviewer?

Comment: @redshark I am just using Qt Creator, no qmlscene or qmlviewer.